# HTML report using Karma unit testing environment

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I am using the **karma** runner to watch and execute my **jasmine** unit tests. Everything is working very well:

```
WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9877/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket OgjbuvCr3-_2Tn4eBIP7 wth id 15958859
..............................................................................................
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7): Executed 123 of 123 SUCCESS (12.052 secs / 12.051 secs)
```

However I am trying to use a [custom reporter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) to generate some html files:

```
npm install karma-jasmine-html-reporter -g
```

And if I choose to generate the html report in the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
...
reporters: ['html'],
...
```

The **karma** environment no longer successfully starts:

```
...
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket 3IOACm6k0JKfDQN3DXii with id 16839683
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined
    at C:/Users/gustavo_domenico/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/html.jasmine.reporter.js?3cbecfb23689b35e47d04a0870eb69d60182fdab:24
```

I tried to install the karma-jasmine and others html based reports but the same error persist. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem? I am having a similar error

Comment: Not really. I just abandoned the custom HTML reporter and I am using Karma to run the test in real time and the Jasmine javascript runner to see the details in a HTML frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem by using `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` plugin. In my case it was related to `karma-jasmine` version (I used an old one). Make sure you use the latest.

Comment: in my case i upgraded to using Jasmine 2